# How does this while loop know when to fail?

Tags: java, while-loop

I was reading about how to program network sockets and ran across this piece of code:

```
try {     
   while (true) {   // This is the line in question
     int i = in.read(  );
     if (i == -1) break;
     System.out.write(i);
   }
 }
 catch (SocketException e) {
   // output thread closed the socket
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println(e);
 }
```

How does the second line know when to fail?  In other words, how does the `while(true)` loop work?  I guess I don't understand 'While what is true?'

Comment: `while (true)` is an infinite loop. It has to be broken from inside in order to stop looping. Usually (as in this case) this is done using [`break`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important line here is:

```
if (i == -1) break;
```

The [`break`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) will exit the current loop when `i == -1`. Without this line it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: So is this an infinite loop otherwise?

Comment: @nkon Yes, without the `break` it is an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 0):

[Shafik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708801/shafik-yaghmour) has told the point. I will just add that `while(true)` means `while (true == true)` because while loop test a boolean condition. This particular condition is always true and the loop will run infinite unless you define a `break` or `return` condition somewhere in it.

Comment: `while(true)` does not means `while (true == true)`. `true == true` just happens to be `true`.